# Problem with bash script executed from website

Tags: bash, shell-script, webserver

I have just begun writing scripts in bash and I am putting some of them on my web server (whihc is located on my virtual Debian 6.0.4 machine).

I have installed lighttpd on this machine.and when I execute for instance this command :

```
TOP=`top -n 1`;
PS=`ps aux`;

echo "that's top\n" $TOP;
echo "ps\n" $PS;
```

Nothing is printed as `$TOP` and for `$PS` the text is written without separation for lines (all is written in a single line). How can I change this ?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a CGI script through lighttpd?

Comment: @Arcege Yes it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of plain `top` is not suitable for displaying on anything but a terminal. You should use the `-b` switch to get plain text output.

And the end of line characters are going to get stripped (replaced by spaces) by your shell with what you're doing - there's no reason for you to store those outputs in variables, you could simply run those commands when you need them.

I'm assuming you're returning the data to a web browser. If that is indeed the case, you should do some minimal HTML formatting if you want a chance at having the output displayed correctly.

Try something like:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo -e "Content-type: text/html\n"
echo "<html><body>"
echo "<h1>top</h1>"
echo "<pre>"
top -b -n 1
echo "</pre>"
echo "<h1>ps</h1>"
echo "<pre>"
ps aux
echo "</pre>"
echo "</body></html>"
```

Comment: Can you tell me why I cannot use this `top -b -n 1 > /home/username/t.txt` ? nothing is created in the home dir

Comment: Probably permission issues. No way to tell really without an error message.

Comment: Actually, the real problem (re: munged output) is that `$TOP` must be written as `"$TOP"` to preserve the spaces. Welcome to Bourne Shell.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that your output is not display is because you are not following the [CGI protocol](http://www.cgi101.com/learn/).  You must send server response headers before any other output.

```
TOP=`top -n 1`;
PS=`ps aux`;

echo "Content-Type: text/plain"  # response header
echo ""                          # end of headers
echo "that's top\n" $TOP;
echo "ps\n" $PS;
```

Use text/plain will give the formatting you want, but will not give the HTML usage like hyperlinks.  For that, use:

```
TOP=`top -n 1`
PS=`ps aux`

echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html>"
echo "<head><title>command output</title></head>"
echo "<body>that's top<br/>"
echo "<pre>$TOP</pre>"
echo "<br/>ps<br/>"
echo "<pre>$PS</pre>"
echo "</body>"
```

Answer (score 1):

If this was run in a terminal, when you echo them you need to put quotes around the variable to keep the newline characters.

```
TOP=`top -b -n 1`;
PS=`ps aux`;

echo "that's top";
echo "$TOP";
echo "ps";
echo "$PS";
```

If the output gets sent to a webpage, then you additionally need the pre tags

```
TOP=`top -b -n 1`;
PS=`ps aux`;
echo "<pre>";
echo "that's top";
echo "$TOP";
echo "ps";
echo "$PS";
echo "</pre>";
```